# How to merge bytes together in C language

Tags: c

X and Y analog values is made of 2 bytes

```
Byte1 : 0 B13 B12 B11 B10 B9 B8 B7 
Byte2 : 0 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0
```

The final X and Y analog value is:

```
0 0 B13 B12 B11 B10 B9 B8 B7  B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0
```

I don't have very good way to implement.  Any suggestions?  Thank you,

Comment: Looks like `result = (byte1 << 8) + byte2;`

Comment: I believe Eugene's correct, except you should shift 7 bits instead of 8. Also, you may need to cast `byte1` into some 16-bit (or larger) integer type, otherwise the shift might result in a 0, and you'll be left with just the value of `byte2`.

Comment: @Milack27 [Integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) will ensure enough bit width for this shift. The result should be stored in a suitably large type, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about having a 14 bit ADC value that is split into HIGH and Low bytes separately.
From your question I am assuming the Low byte has bits [6-0] and the High byte has bits [13-7]. You can make them a single value by shifting bits appropriately.

```c
uint16_t value = (high_byte << 7) | low_byte;
```

How does this work?
You shift high_byte 7 times to the left.

```
High_byte : b13 b12 b11 b10 b09 b08 b07   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 (shifted 7 times)
Low_byte  :   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 b06 b05 b04 b03 b02 b01 b00
```

Finally ORing this gives you the result.

Comment: `high_byte` here is Byte1 (MSB) and `low_byte` is Byte2 from your example

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t byte1 = 0b01010101;  // 0x55 in hex
    uint8_t byte2 = 0b01111111;  // 0x7F in hex
    
    uint16_t result = (byte1<<7) | byte2;
    // Expected result: 0b0010101011111111
    // which is Hex: 0x2AFF
    
    printf("0x%02X\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I think this example code illustrates what you are describing.

`byte1` and `byte2` are chosen with recognizable bit-patterns:

- `byte1`: high bit is zero, other bits are alternating.
- `byte2`: high bit is zero, other bits are all set

Then I shift `byte1` over 7 times so that `B13` has two leading zeros, as you described, and OR in `byte2`

Comment: Aside: Binary constants are a [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants).

Comment: ...which is exactly why I put the Hex values in the comments.  `0b` for clarity of example, but `0x` if needed for portability.